# Use column to create table with fixed width

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Can `column` create columns of a fixed width? I couldn't find the option in the man page.

```
$ echo "a b c
d eeeeee f" | column -t
a  b       c
d  eeeeee  f
```

Comment: What output are you looking to get? All columns the same width (of the widest field)?

Comment: @glennjackman I supply a fixed width ex. 8, then each column is 8 chars wide.

Comment: If `column` doesn't do what you want, there's always `awk` e.g. `awk -v w=8 '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%*s",w,$i); printf "\n"}'`